# The button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
<input id="input"></input>
<button id="button" onclick="evaluate()">Submit</button>
<br>
<p id="id"></p>
</body>
<script>
var a = 1;
var b = 100;
var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * (b-a)) + a;
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = ("Pick a number between 1 and 100. I will try to guess it. I think it's " + z + ".");
var y = document.getElementById("input").value;
function evaluate() {
  var y = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if (y == 0) {
    a = x + 1;
    z = (a+b)/2;
    if (z%2==1) {
      z = z-0.5
    }
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = ("Now I think it's " + z);
    stopEvent();
  }
  if (y == 2) {
    b = x - 1;
    z = (a+b)/2;
    if (z%2==1) {
      z = z-0.5;
    }
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = ("Now I think it's " + z);
    stopEvent();
  }
  if (y == 1) {
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = ("Yay! I'm so smart.");
    stopEvent();
  }
}
</script>
```

When I click on the button it doesn't think of another integer, it does nothing. I can't find any typos. This program is supposed to guess your number in 7 guesses. You think of a number between 1 and 100, and it first chooses a random integer 1-100, then you tell it if it's too high or too low, then it resets its range according to what you told it, and it chooses another integer, and another, until it narrows down to 1 integer.

Comment: Did you take a look at the JavaScript console for any errors?

Comment: The debugger is saying that `x` is undefined

Comment: Probably because `x` **isn't** defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `x` is never defined. You jump right into using `x` in a calculation when it is undefined. What is `x` supposed to be? Once you define `x` everything should work.

```
    a = x + 1; // What is x?
```

If you do not define `x` then your function `evaluate()` will break.

Answer (score 1):

[evaluate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.evaluate) is a predefined method available, so change the name of your method name if you see a conflict.

Now as mentioned by mwilson, you are using variable `x` without declaring it with some value.

I guess you have already defined `stopEvent()` in your code or else you will get an error there also.

Comment: Didn't catch the `evaluate()` usage. Good catch.